# HTML/CSS acting very weird in my Rails 4 app (height not customizable etc)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two questions with this post. The first is why does the Toyota Camry act like that? [image]

Here's the code:

```
#posts
    - @posts.each do |post|
        .post
            .post_content
                .title
                    %h2
                        = link_to truncate((post.title), length: 25), post
                %p
                    $
                    = post.price
                .post_image
                    = link_to image_tag(post.image.url), post
                .data.clearfix
                    %p.username
                        Listing by
                        = post.user.name
                    %p.buttons
                        %span
                            %i.fa.fa-comments-o
                            = post.inquiries.count
                        %span
                            %i.fa.fa-thumbs-o-up
                            = post.get_likes.size
```

The CSS:

```
#posts {
    .post {
        width: 20%;
        float: right;
        margin: 1rem 1.5%;
        border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
        /*height: auto;*/
        .post_image {
            height: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            img {
                width: 100%;
                border-radius: .3rem .3rem 0 0;
            }
        }
        .post_content {
            margin: 1rem;
            h2 {
                margin: 0;
                font-weight: 100;
                padding: 1rem 5%;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
                font-size: 1.5rem;
                a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    /*color: #333233;*/
                    &:hover {
                        color: #6E58E0;
                    }
                }
            }
            .data {
                padding: .75rem 5%;
                color: #969696;
                .username, .buttons {
                    margin: 0;
                    font-size: 1rem;
                }
                .username {
                    float: left;
                }
                .buttons {
                    float: right;
                    span {
                        margin-left: .5rem;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think that's everything that's working on the page, but if I'm missing something please let me know.

I've been having a lot of problems with it, trying every way I know how to fix it.

I also didn't have much success in making the individual post element the same width and height, evenly. This is the second part to this question. I'm trying to get the title, image, etc to be evenly throughout each post.

Any help is appreciated as always. Thanks

EDIT: I'm not quite sure what you mean by rendered HTML but is this it
[image]

Additionally, the same CSS and HTML applied to another part of the page works correctly
[image]

Comment: It would be handy for you to post the rendered HTML here as well.

Comment: "...why does the Toyota Camry act like that?" What are you talking about? You seem to think that a problem that seems obvious to you will also be equally obvious to everyone else, except we're not you. If you expect help, you're going to have to be specific about the problems you think you're seeing.

Comment: It's at the bottom when it's supposed to be inline with the other posts. I tried to set it up so every column has 4 posts

Comment: Is possible to mock up the result you do want to see? Like @MarsAtomic, I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what you want to see.

Comment: I see what he wants. He was talking about the silver Camry in the lower right, not the red Camry in the upper right, which is being displayed perfectly. He wants all his thumbnails displayed in a perfect grid, where every cell is the same width and height and thumbs appear visually to be added sequentially to available cells. Right now, that silver Camry is floating off in a corner by itself.

Comment: Thank you @MarsAtomic, that's exactly what I want. Sorry for not clarifying in the post. Can anyone help me? I thought it was fixed by charging the width percentage to a lower %, but it's not :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following line to your "#posts .post" CSS

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: That didn't do anything :(

Comment: @HenryLee If it's alive, I'd like to take a look.